Examples of non-smooth interacting systems: Can motion of a particle be activated/deactivated by the presence/absence of surrounding particles?
Are there any physical situations of interacting particle systems in which the motion of individual particles can be activated and deactivated in response to the presence or absence of surrounding particles? There could be something in the spirit of dry friction.

How about superconductivity?

Sound like what you have in a transistor.
